# how to install 'intl PHP extension' with Wamp server

Tags: php, wamp

i want to install 'intl PHP extension' on my WAMP. i am running Wamp on windows.

i have looked online but cannot find any guidance on how to do this. does anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Can you outline what you have tried so far?

Comment: You should have the DLLs already on a Windows distribution, you probably just need to uncomment `;extension=php_intl.dll` (remove the leading semi-colon) in your php.ini file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

on wamp icon click on php -> php extensions -> php_intl then restart the server

Comment: when you enable an extension in wamp, it automatically restarts apache for you :)

Comment: Also, from CakePHP's [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#requirements), 'In WAMP, the intl extension is “activated” by default but not working. To make it work you have to go to php folder (by default) C:\wamp\bin\php\php{version}, copy all the files that looks like icu*.dll and paste them into the apache bin directory C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin. Then restart all services and it should be OK.'

Answer (score 3):

According the the comment this is the content

> In both XAMPP and WAMP, the mbstring extension is working by default.
>
> In XAMPP, intl extension is included but you have to uncomment
>   extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini and restart the server through the
>   XAMPP Control Panel.
>
> In WAMP, the intl extension is “activated” by default but not working.
>   To make it work you have to go to php folder (by default)
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php{version}, copy all the files that looks like
>   icu*.dll and paste them into the apache bin directory
>   C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin. Then restart all services and
>   it should be OK.

Hope it helps