# How to get a word in string with relevant keyword?

Tags: php

My language is Vietnamese, so I am having a problem with getting the exact word from the relevant keyword. I have one string and one keyword:

```
$mystring = "từ khóa a,từ khóa b, từ khóa c";
$mykeyword = "tu khoa b";
```

How can I use `$mykeyword` to get `từ khóa b` from `$mystring`?

Thank you!

Comment: You can try this answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called UTF-8 Normalization, I believe.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7934397/145279) explains some of the foundations. Try this:

```
php > $mystring = "từ khóa a,từ khóa b, từ khóa c";
php > $mykeyword = "tu khoa b";
php > var_dump(transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\u7fff] remove', $mystring));
string(30) "tu khoa a,tu khoa b, tu khoa c"
php >
```

Now, you can use the normal string manipulation functions to see if `$mykeyword` is contained within `$mystring`. Note that characters which don't have ASCII translations will be removed.

Note that for this to work, you need the PHP `intl` module installed (often a package called `php5-intl`). See [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php).

You can also use the [Normalizer](https://secure.php.net/normalizer) and `preg_replace()` to strip accents:

```
php > var_dump(preg_replace('/\p{Mn}/u', '', Normalizer::normalize($mystring, Normalizer::FORM_KD)));
string(30) "tu khoa a,tu khoa b, tu khoa c"
php >
```

Yet another way is to use [`iconv()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

```
php > var_dump(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]+/', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $mystring)));
string(25) "t khoa at khoa b t khoa c"
```

However, as you can see, the `ừ` didn't properly translate.

Comment: Why I'm seeing _"**Fatal error**: Call to undefined function transliterator_transliterate() in **C:\xampp\htdocs\...\index.php** on line **5**"_ upon testing?

Comment: Because you need the `intl` module :) See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431788/how-to-install-intl-php-extension-with-wamp-server) for how to enable it on WAMP.

Comment: Do you think that module is already installed on most shared web hosts?

Comment: Most likely. It's part of the standard PHP distribution. If it's not, for some reason, you should be able to get them to install it. I added another way to do it without `intl` that should work on any PHP 5.3.0+ installation.

Comment: How did you install PHP? This is probably as simple as installing `php5-intl`, or at worst, running `pecl install intl`.

Comment: Ok follow instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll)! :)

Comment: Add the `iconv` method as well. `preg_replace('/[^A-Z|^a-z|^0-9]/', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $content));` http://ideone.com/jOw5Cu